# note: previous implicit declaration of 'borde' was here

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un juego para mi materia de desarrollo de videojuegos, muy parecido al pong, solo que con dos raquetas abajo, una pared enmedio y dos pelotas. en el siguiente codigo solo pinto el campo con las matrices, pero el compilador me marca solo dos errores en el siguiente codigo

> **61   6   C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\alv.c    [Warning] conflicting types for 'borde'
>
> 55  5   C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\alv.c    [Note] previous implicit declaration of 'borde' was here**

la consola solo se muestra negra y no muestra nada, este es el codigo completo donde tengo este error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define V 21 //tamaño vertical del campo
#define H 75 //tamaño horizontal del campo

void inicio (char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY, int pelX2, int pelY2, int inijug, int finjug, int inijug2, int finjug2);
void leercampo(char campo[V][H]);
void pel(char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY);
void raqjug(char campo[V][H], int inijug, int finjug);

int main(){
    int pelX; //POSICION X,Y DE LA PELOTA
    int pelY;
    int pelX2;
    int pelY2;

    int inijug; //POSICION INICIO Y FIN DE LA RAQUETA
    int finjug;
    int inijug2;
    int finjug2;

    int modX; //DIRECCION X,Y DE LA PELOTA
    int modY; 
    int modX2;
    int modY2;

    char campo[V][H]; //DIMENCIONES DEL CAMPO

    pelX= 38;
    pelY= 3;
    
    pelX2=38;
    pelY2= 5;
    
    inijug= 15;
    finjug = 25;

    inijug2= H-25;
    finjug2 = H-15;

    inicio(campo, pelX, pelY, pelX2, pelY2, inijug, finjug, inijug2, finjug2);
    leercampo(campo);
    system("pause");


    return 0;
}
void inicio (char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY, int pelX2, int pelY2, int inijug, int finjug, int inijug2, int finjug2) //esta funcion inicializa la matriz campo
{
    borde(campo);
    raqjug(campo, inijug, finjug);
    raqjug(campo, inijug2, finjug2);
    pel(campo, pelX, pelY);
    pel(campo, pelX2, pelY2);
}
void borde(char campo[V][H]) //esta funcion pinta el borde en el campo
{ 
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i==V-1)
            {
                campo[i][j]=219;
            }else if (j==0 || j==H-1)
            {
                campo[i][j]=219;
            }else if (j==37 && i>8)
            {
                campo[i][j]=219;
            }else
            {
                campo[i][j]=' ';
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

void pel(char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY) // esta funcion asigna posicion a la pelota
{
    campo[pelX][pelY]=254;
}

void raqjug(char campo[V][H], int inijug, int finjug) //esta funcion asigna las posiciones de la raqueta
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 19; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = inijug; j < finjug; j++)
        {
            campo[i][j]=223;
        }
        
    }
    
}
void leercampo(char campo[V][H]) //esta funcion imprime en pantalla la matriz campo
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",campo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: No tienes prototipo de `borde()` definido. Tendrá que ver?

Comment: buena observación pero aun así sigue el problema.

Comment: Pon la implementación función `void borde(char campo[V][H])` antes de llamar a dicha función, es decir, antes de la propia implementación de la función `inicio`.

Answer (score 0):

> > pero el compilador me marca solo dos errores en el siguiente codigo

No es un error de compilación, sino, una advertencia. La diferencia es simple, con un error no puedes ejecutar el programa, en cambio con un *warning*, sí.

> [Warning] conflicting types for 'borde'
> [Note] previous implicit declaration of 'borde' was here

El compilador te está tratando de decir que se inventó la declaración de la función `borde` y asume que la función retorna un `int`:

```c
int borde(char campo[V][H]);
```

Como verás, esta **declaración implicita** que se ha inventado el compilador entra en conflicto con la definición de `borde`:

```c
void borde(char campo[V][H])
{
      // código.
}
```

En otras palabras, la declaración y la definición no coinciden, su tipo de valor de retorno son diferentes y por esa razón el compilador avisa lo que está haciendo. Este *warning* se debe de arreglar porque conduce un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

La solución más sencilla es agregar de manera **explicita** la declaración de `borde`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define V 21 //tamaño vertical del campo
#define H 75 //tamaño horizontal del campo

void inicio (char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY, int pelX2, int pelY2, int inijug, int finjug, int inijug2, int finjug2);
void leercampo(char campo[V][H]);
void pel(char campo[V][H], int pelX, int pelY);
void raqjug(char campo[V][H], int inijug, int finjug);

// Declaramos la función 'borde'.
void borde(char campo[V][H]);
```

Como nota adicional, recuerda que en C para llamar a una función antes debe de estar definida o declarada.

**Ejemplo (1):**

```c
// Declaración de foo:
void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    // Antes debe de estar declarada la función "foo" para poder llamar a "foo".
    foo();
    return 0;
}

// Definición de foo:
void foo(void)
{
    // code.
}
```

**Ejemplo (2):**

```c
// Definición de foo:
void foo(void)
{
    // code.
}

int main(void)
{
    // Antes debe de estar definida la función "foo" para poder llamar a "foo".
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

### Observación

Cuando declaras la función, no necesitas especificar el nombre del parámetro, es opcional.